# Two sided animation for horizontal bar chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts

I am trying to implement a similar chart as this
https://jasonneylon.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/two-sided-horizontal-barchart-using-d3-js/

I need an animation that starts from the mid point. i.e. the left chart should transition from right to left and the right chart from left to right having the origin as the middle.

i tried doing

```
.transition()
        .delay(100)
        .attr({'x': rightOffset, 'y': yPosByIndex, height: y.rangeBand(), width: xTo})
        .duration(500);
```

but it transitions the whole graph from left to right.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to set the initial position of the bars to the center.

Comment: That would work only for the rectangle on the right side

Comment: No. You set initial position to center and width to 0 for all and then transition to the final position and width. Works for both. See [this example](http://vis.stanford.edu/jheer/d3/pyramid/shift.html).